# Converting time to POSIX after forcing time zone

Tags: r, datetime, posix, lubridate

I have vector of times:

```
library(lubridate)
> test
[1] "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC"
[5] "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC"
```

All of the class POSIX:

```
> class(test)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

However when I force conversion of time zone:

```
test <- format(force_tz(test, tz = 'UTC'), tz ='America/Los_Angeles', usetz=TRUE)
```

This also forces the time vectors into a character class which cannot be converted back to POSIX.

```
> class(test)
[1] "character"
as.POSIXct(test, format = "%Y-%m-%d HH:MM:SS")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What could be the issue here and what is the workaround to changing timezone and retaining POSIX class?

Comment: Guess there's a problem with your format also `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: what problem is that?

Comment: `HH` instead of `%H`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lubridate` based answer using `with_tz`

```
ss <- strptime(test,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'UCT')
lubridate::with_tz(ss, "America/Los_Angeles")
```

Output:

```
> test <- "2018-01-13 22:23:00 UTC"
> ss <- strptime(test,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'UCT')
> lubridate::with_tz(ss, "America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2018-01-13 14:23:00 PST"
```

Please note I've used strptime since my input is a text but in your case you can just simply use `with_tz`

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `force_tz` without running the results through `format`. `force_tz` does the time zone conversion, and `format` is what is then converting it to character:

```
converted = force_tz(test, tz ='America/Los_Angeles')
```

Output:

```
> converted
[1] "2018-01-13 22:23:00 PST" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 PST" 
    "2018-01-13 22:23:00 PST" "2018-01-13 22:23:00 PST"
> class(converted)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

If you instead need to convert the timezone (which is not what `force_tz` does), use `with_tz`:

```
> with_tz(test, tz = 'America/Los_Angeles')
[1] "2018-01-13 14:23:00 PST" "2018-01-13 14:23:00 PST" 
    "2018-01-13 14:23:00 PST" "2018-01-13 14:23:00 PST"
```

Comment: yes except you are not converting to `PST` - the time is still in `UTC`

Comment: OK, `force_tz` assumes that the displayed times are already correct for the desired time zone, and just sets the timezone. If you want to get the equivalent time in the target timezone, it's `with_tz(test, tz = 'America/Los_Angeles')` instead